# Filter condions in xml with same tag names in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to add two filter conditions and I am able to achieve one result. I want to get the results if I am doing search with the  tags(here I am stuck).

XML file

```
<root>
 <DescriptorRecord DescriptorClass = "1">
   <DescriptorName>
     <String>abc</String>
   </DescriptorName>
  <ConceptList>
   <Concept PreferredConceptYN="Y">
    <TermList>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="Y"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="Y"  RecordPreferredTermYN="Y">
        <String>abc</String>
     </Term>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="N"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="N"  RecordPreferredTermYN="N">
        <String>pqr</String>
     </Term>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="N"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="Y"  RecordPreferredTermYN="N">
        <String>xyz</String>
    </Term>
   </TermList>
   </Concept>
  </ConceptList>
 </DescriptorRecord>
 <DescriptorRecord DescriptorClass = "1">
  <DescriptorName>
   <String>123</String>
  </DescriptorName>
  <ConceptList>
   <Concept PreferredConceptYN="Y">
    <TermList>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="Y"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="Y"  RecordPreferredTermYN="Y">
        <String>123</String>
     </Term>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="N"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="N"  RecordPreferredTermYN="N">
        <String>456</String>
     </Term>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="N"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="Y"  RecordPreferredTermYN="N">
        <String>789</String>
    </Term>
   </TermList>
   </Concept>
  </ConceptList>
 </DescriptorRecord>
 </root>
```

C# code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(myXMLfile);

XmlNodeList descriptors = doc.SelectNodes("root/DescriptorRecord");

#region
foreach (XmlNode desc in descriptors)
{
    if (desc != null && desc.HasChildNodes)
    {
        var node = desc.SelectSingleNode("DescriptorName/String");

        if (node != null)
        {
            String descName = node.InnerText.ToLower().Replace(SPACE, string.Empty);

            if (string.Equals(descName, lowerCaseGeneralTerm))
            {
                //Read a collection of nodes if your file have many <Term> nodes
                XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = desc.SelectNodes("ConceptList/Concept/TermList/Term/String");

                if (xmlNodeList != null)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodeList)
                    {
                        conceptNames.Add(xmlNode.InnerText);
                    }

                    var result = conceptNames.Where(x => x.Replace(SPACE, string.Empty).Equals(lowerCaseGeneralTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

                    if (result != null && result.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        //Seprate concepts with new line 
                        String splitConceptWithComma = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, conceptNames.ToArray());
                        txtMeSHTerms.Text = splitConceptWithComma;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Clear the list after displaying result so for next search it won't combine previous + current result.
    conceptNames.Clear();
}
```

Result :

If you search for "abc" from `<DescriptorName>` tag

```
<DescriptorName>
   <String>abc</String>
</DescriptorName>
```

I am getting following result.

abc
pqr
xyz

which satisfies my one condition.

2nd condition is, if you search from `<Term>` tag  then it should return the same results.

```
 <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="Y"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="Y"  RecordPreferredTermYN="Y">
            <String>abc</String>
         </Term>
```

I hope this information is enough. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an XPath query to look for the node value, then select it's `TermList` ancestor:

```
XmlNodeList xmlNodeList 
            = desc.SelectNodes("root//ConceptList/Concept/TermList/Term/String[text() = 'pqr']/ancestor::TermList/Term/String");
```

This should give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you want the 2nd condition to be implemented specifically, but you can search by `<Term>` string and return all `<Term>`s string in the same `<TermList>` parent using XPath. XPath example given serch term "abc" (formatted for readability) :

```
/root
/DescriptorRecord
/ConceptList
/Concept
/TermList[Term/String='abc']
/Term
/String
```

Above XPath will return "abc", "pqr", and "xyz" string nodes given sample XML posted.